# Smart Card Reader on Android via WiFi or USB

Tags: android, credit-card, smartcard

I have been searched on google and I could old information (most of them), without solution. Would be possible to communicate and Android device (Samsung Galaxy SII) with an Smart Card Reader like http://betteroffer.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/chip_pin_02.jpg via USB(if the reader does have it) and/or Wifi + Manucture's SDK.

Have anyone made any integration like?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: it depends, are you talking about a commercial version of Android or Android-open-source ?

Comment: Sorry, would be with Android OS running on any commercial device such as Samsung Galaxy SIII. thank you for attention

Comment: then the answer is no because the commercial phones use a monolithic build for the Android kernel, in other words it's not possible to load kernel modules like drivers, and you need drivers for any peripherals that you want to connect to Android to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess chances are slim for wired access: even most tablets are unable to play the USB-host but can only emulate a drive for a PC. A first check would be, to connect a USB-memory-stick to the smartphone and see, whether access to files is possible. 
Easiest (direct) method for smart phone-> smart card coupling is NFC, but smart phone models supporting it are definitely the minority and if your card is contact-based only, you are out of luck. WiFi could work over an intermediate intelligent unit, but I'm not aware of a smart card reader directly supporting WiFi.

Comment: yeahh I know, I am out of luck. Unfortunately I cannot use a smartcard buit-in bluetooth due to the environment's restrictions.
Thank you for attention @guidot

Comment: Then again, a quick google suggested: http://techblog.goelite.org/how-to-enable-the-usb-host-mode-of-your-samsung-galaxy-s2/

Comment: Maybe something like a Raspberry PI with WiFi module would do the trick? You've got to power it though, *and* create some protocol (e.g. using the `javax.smartcardio` interface).

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can also take a look at Syncotek smart [card reader](http://www.syncotek.com/product/card_reader_1.html), such as the model Syncotek SC-600P, it is one USB smart card reader that has Built-in antenna for contactless tag access, with card reading distance of up to 50 mm(depending on tag type), i think this one may support Android devices.